# Why does my fork of a gem not work in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, thin

I [forked](https://github.com/cstump/negative-captcha) the gem `negative-captcha` to make it work with `SimpleForm`. I changed my app to work with the fork in development mode.

Then, I deployed to stage (Rails 3.2.16, Ruby 2.1.1; powered by Thin on Linux). When I hit a page that uses the gem, I got a 500 error: `uninitialized constant NegativeCaptcha`. In the console on the staging server, I tried referencing `NegativeCaptcha`, and the class was there. 
I cannot figure out why the running application cannot find/is not loading the `NegativeCaptcha` class of my fork. I cannot reproduce the issue locally (if I run my app with Thin in production on my Mac, it works fine).

I'm also out of ideas on how to debug the issue. Debug statements in the fork and in my app have not helped at all. If you can help me resolve this issue, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: is it in your gemfile how do you reference it?

Comment: Thanks @Doon. My Gemfile has `gem 'negative_captcha', '0.3.4', git: 'git@github.com:cstump/negative-captcha.git'` in it.

Comment: Check your Gemfile.lock

Comment: I'm not certain how to read the Gemfile.lock, but `negative_captcha (= 0.3.4)!` is under the `DEPENDENCIES` section of the file and this is at the top: ```GIT
  remote: git@github.com:cstump/negative-captcha.git
  revision: a616eb0ce7eb471919d200bd0bf99e4590948a24
  specs:
    negative_captcha (0.3.4)
      actionpack
      activesupport```

Comment: [Here is a gist of my Gemfile.lock](https://gist.github.com/cstump/5ca0f95409d382609ff7)

Comment: can you gist your Gemfile as well.

Comment: [I gist'd the Gemfile](https://gist.github.com/cstump/5ca0f95409d382609ff7)

Answer (score 1):

Try this gem declaration:

```
gem 'negative_captcha', github: 'cstump/negative-captcha'
```

And ensure it is not in development group

Comment: same result if I use this declaration